# Python Pandas Regression

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, statistics, regression

[enter image description here][1]I am struggling to figure out if regression is the route I need to go in order to solve my current challenge with Python. Here is my scenario:

- I have a Pandas Dataframe that is 195 rows x 25 columns
- All data (except for index and headers) are integers
- I have one specific column (Column B) that I would like compared to all other columns
- Attempting to determine if there is a range of numbers in any of the columns that influences or impacts column B
- An example of the results I would like to calculate in Python is something similar to: Column B is above 3.5 when data in Column D is between 10.20 - 16.4

The examples I've been reading online with Regression in Python appear to produce charts and statistics that I don't need (or maybe I am interpreting incorrectly). I believe the proper wording to describe what I am asking, is to identify specific values or a range of values that are linear between two columns in a Pandas dataframe.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: So what you want to achieve is to determine if Column B is above 3.5 when data in Column D is between 10.20 - 16.4? can you provide some sample data frame?

Comment: I want to understand which numbers or ranges influence the outcome of column B.  I'll post a sample data frame shortly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to add attachments. copy/paste of the data frame is not displaying properly.

Answer (score 2):

Your goals sound very much like exploratory data analysis at this point. You should probably first calculate the `correlation` between your target `column B` and any other `column` using `pandas.Series.corr` (which really is the same as bivariate regression), which you could `list`:

```
other_cols = [col for col in df1.columns if col !='B']
corr_B = [{other: df.loc[:, 'B'].corr(df.loc[:, other])} for other in other_col]
```

To get a handle on specific ranges, I would recommend looking at:

- the `cut` and `qcut` functionality to `bin` your data as you like and either plot or correlate subsets accordingly: see docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.cut.html) and [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.qcut.html).

To visualize bivariate and simple multivariate relationships, I would recommend

- the `seaborn` package because it includes various types of plots designed to help you get a quick grasp of covariation among variables. See for instance the examples for univariate and bivariate distributions [here](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/distributions.html#plotting-bivariate-distributions), linear relationship plots [here](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/regression.html), and categorical data plots [here](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical.html).

The above should help you understand bivariate relationships. Once you want to progress to multivariate relationships, you could return to the [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) or [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/regression.html) packages best suited for this in `python` IMHO. Hope this helps to get you started.

Comment: Than you so much for your post and recommendations.

Comment: You're welcome. Just let me know if you need clarification on the above, or if this answers your question for now.